# How can I recover polygons and normal maps from compiled games through emulation of D3D or OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, directx, graphics, rendering, graphics-programming

I am trying to generate labeled training data for an artificial visual cortex to learn on. I'm looking for a tool that will, instead of rendering the scene at each pixel just give me the pre-rendered data associated with each pixel. Presumably something like:

[x,y] -> [normal, depth, color, lighting, (lens flares?), texture, etc]

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Easy? No idea. You might want to consider using an open-source game and modifying the source code.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, and someone already did it with Starcraft (pretty awesome btw) -> https://graphics.stanford.edu/~mdfisher/GameAIs.html

Comment: @glampert woo, thanks, hopefully this works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RenderDoc](https://github.com/baldurk/renderdoc) can get you a lot, if not all, of that info.

I've previously used it during development to pull out my normal-maps, light maps etc. It also pulls out all the textures used in any fragment shaders etc.

Comment: This is definitely what I needed, thank you for your help.